# Get Invaild Argument Error with Google Wallet API when create a generic base class on PHP

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-wallet

I tried to implement Google Wallet API to create Generic Card Pass with PHP and I'm using the demo code described there: https://github.com/google-wallet/rest-samples/blob/main/php/demo_generic.php . When I create a class with only id as class definition (['id' => $issuerId . '.' . $classSuffix]) it works but if I use the class base below I get and Invalid Argument Error:

```
    Google\Service\Exception {
      #message: """
        {
    
          "error": {
    
            "code": 400,
    
            "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    
            "errors": [
    
              {
    
                "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    
                "domain": "global",
    
                "reason": "badRequest"
    
              }
    
            ],
    
            "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    
          }
    
        }
    
        """
      #code: 400
      #file: "../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php"
      #errors: array:1 [
        0 => array:3 [
          "message" => "Request contains an invalid argument."
          "domain" => "global"
          "reason" => "badRequest"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

My class base definition:

```
$classDef = [
                'id' => $issuerId .  '.' . self::CLASS_SUFFIX,
                'classTemplateInfo' => [
                    'cardTemplateOverride' => [
                        'cardRowTemplateInfos' => [
                            [
                                'twoItems' => [
                                    'startItem' => [
                                        'firstValue' => [
                                            'fields' => [
                                                [
                                                    'fieldPath' => 'object.textModulesData["points"]'
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    'endItem' => [
                                        'firstValue' => [
                                            'fields' => [
                                                [
                                                    'fieldPath' => 'object.textModulesData["contacts"]'
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'detailsTemplateOverride' => [
                        'detailsItemInfos' => [
                            [
                                'item' => [
                                    'firstValue' => [
                                        'fields' => [
                                            [
                                                'fieldPath' => 'class.imageModulesData["event_banner"]'
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                'item' => [
                                    'firstValue' => [
                                        'fields' => [
                                            [
                                                'fieldPath' => 'class.textModulesData["game_overview"]'
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                'item' => [
                                    'firstValue' => [
                                        'fields' => [
                                            [
                                                'fieldPath' => 'class.linksModuleData.uris["official_site"]'
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'imageModulesData' => [
                    [
                        'mainImage' => [
                            'sourceUri' => [
                                'uri' => 'https=>//storage.googleapis.com/wallet-lab-tools-codelab-artifacts-public/google-io-2021-card.png'
                            ],
                            'contentDescription' => [
                                'defaultValue' => [
                                    'language' => 'en-US',
                                    'value' => 'Google I/O 2022 Banner'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        'id' => 'event_banner'
                    ]
                ],
                'textModulesData' => [
                    [
                        'header' => 'Gather points meeting new people at Google I/O',
                        'body' => 'Join the game and accumulate points in this badge by meeting other attendees in the event.',
                        'id' => 'game_overview'
                    ]
                ],
                'linksModuleData' => [
                    'uris' => [
                        [
                            'uri' => 'https=>//io.google/2022/',
                            'description' => 'Official I/O \'22 Site',
                            'id' => 'official_site'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```

N.B: When I use the exemple with nodejs it works perfectly

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to quote the exact, full error message please? Don't paraphrase or abbreviate error messages - it just creates unnecessary ambiguity.

Comment: @ADyson I added the error object

Comment: In order to properly answer, we need to see the entire HTTP payload, not just the value associated to `genericClasses` in your associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'm going to use createJwtNewObjects method because it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has arrived here: I found one answer that may make this snippet work.

Change `class.imageModulesData["event_banner"]` to `class.imageModulesData['event_banner']`!

It seems that references starting with `class.` may only work with single quotes in some cases.